# Asciidoctor parametetrized template

Tags: asciidoctor

I am using asciidoctor using asciidoctor-maven-plugin. In my document (actually documentation), I have one block repeated many times. Is there any way to do include with parameters.

What I want in pseudocode, I can't find how to write it:

template:

```
=== HTTP request
include::{snippets}/{variable}/http-request.adoc[]
=== HTTP response
include::{snippets}/{variable}/http-response.adoc[]
```

Usage

```
include template[variable=customer]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can [redefine attributes](http://discuss.asciidoctor.org/Redefining-attributes-tp3515.html). With this tree:

```
Folder
|   main.adoc
|   template.adoc
|
\---code
    +---first
    |       http-request.adoc
    |       http-response.adoc
    |
    \---second
            http-request.adoc
            http-response.adoc
```

My `main.adoc` file looks like this:

```
:snippets: code

== First Chapter

:variable: first

include::template.adoc[]

== Second Chapter

:variable: second

include::template.adoc[]

== End

This is the end.
```

---

The previous example works, but I have the feeling that this is not exactly what you want.

If you are looking for a Macro example, have a look at this maven & java example: [java-extension-example](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-examples/tree/master/java-extension-example).